# Fpdf Barcode in Dompdf

Tags: fpdf, dompdf

Is it possible to put an `fpdf` syntax in `dompdf`? Because I'm trying to put a barcode in `dompdf` which I don't know how. So I'm trying to put the `fpdf` barcode syntax inside my `dompdf`. Any help would be appreciated.

AddPage();    $pdf->EAN13(10,10, '123445', 5, 0.5, 9);    $pdf->Output();?>

Comment: But I'm having this error. FPDF error: Some data has already been output, can't send PDF file

Comment: Without details you're asking the community to guess what's causing your problem.  Please read the help documentation on asking questions: https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking then consider deleting this question and asking again when you're ready.

Answer (score 0):

Inside my php file i put this:

```
<?php require ('fpdf_barcode.php');    
$pdf = new PDF_BARCODE('P', 'mm', 'A4');    
$pdf->AddPage();    
$pdf->EAN13(10,10, '123445', 5, 0.5, 9);    
$pdf->Output();?>
```